# Why the scrollview doesn't get updated with new data from array?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to send and then display them in the `scrollview` `realtime`. But nothing shows up. How to solve it? So, basically when the user types the `message` into a `textbox` then it will be saved in `array` and then it will be populated to the `crollView in realtime` so the user can view all the messages.

**Error:** No errors, it just isn't visible.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SingleMessageBubbleModel: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var text: String
    var received: Bool
    var timeStamp: Date
  
 }

var messagesDBArray : [SingleMessageBubbleModel] = []

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showOnTheSpotMessaging: Bool = true
    @State var textTyped: String
  
    
    var body: some View {
  
  
            if (showOnTheSpotMessaging) {
  
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                                ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                                    ScrollView {
                                        
                                    LazyVStack {
                                        ForEach(messagesDBArray, id: \.id) { message in
                                            MessageBubble(message: message)
                                            
                                     }
                                    }
                                    }
                                    .padding(.top, 10)
                                    .background(.gray)
                                    .onChange(of: messagesDBArray.count) { id in
                                       
                                        withAnimation {
                                            proxy.scrollTo(id, anchor: .bottom)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                                .frame( height: 200, alignment: .bottomLeading)
                            }
               
  
                    
                
           
                        HStack () {
                        TextEditor (text: $textTyped)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .leading)
                         
                             
                            Button ("Send", action: {
                                messagesDBArray.append(SingleMessageBubbleModel(text: textTyped, received: true, timeStamp: Date()))
                            })
                        }
       
                    }
                }
 
            }
}
 
struct MessageBubble: View {
    
    var message: SingleMessageBubbleModel
    @State private var showTime = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: message.received ? .leading : .trailing) {
            HStack {
                Text(message.text)
                    .padding()
                    .background(message.received ? Color.gray : Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(30)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: 300, alignment: message.received ? .leading : .trailing)
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation {
                showTime.toggle()
                }
            }
            
            if showTime {
                 
                Text("\(message.timeStamp.formatted(.dateTime.hour().minute()))")
                    .font(.caption2)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .padding(message.received ? .leading : .trailing, 25)
                }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: message.received ? .leading : .trailing)
        .padding(message.received ? .leading : .trailing)
        .padding(.horizontal, 4)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself why would it? How does SwiftUI get notified that there has been a change so it can reload the `body`? Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when the button is pressed, your property `messagesDBArray` is well and truly append with the new value.

However, and it's really important to understand this point in swiftUI, nothing triggers the refresh of the view.

I suggest you two solutions:

- If you don't need `messagesDBArray` to be outside of `ContentView`:

You just have to add `messagesDBArray` as a state in `ContentView` like following

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var messagesDBArray : [SingleMessageBubbleModel] = []
    @State private var showOnTheSpotMessaging: Bool = true
    @State var textTyped: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        if (showOnTheSpotMessaging) {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                        ScrollView {
                            LazyVStack {
                                ForEach(messagesDBArray, id: \.id) { message in
                                    MessageBubble(message: message)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.top, 10)
                        .background(.gray)
                        .onChange(of: messagesDBArray.count) { id in
                            
                            withAnimation {
                                proxy.scrollTo(id, anchor: .bottom)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame( height: 200, alignment: .bottomLeading)
                }
                HStack () {
                    TextEditor (text: $textTyped)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .leading)
                    Button ("Send", action: {
                        messagesDBArray.append(SingleMessageBubbleModel(text: textTyped, received: true, timeStamp: Date()))
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- If you need `messagesDBArray` to be outside of `ContentView`:

1- Create a `class` (`ViewModel` or `Service` or whatever you wan to call it) with `messagesDBArray` as a `@Published` property

```
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var messagesDBArray : [SingleMessageBubbleModel] = []
}
```

2- Observe this `class` in `ContentView` in order to append and receive the update

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    @State private var showOnTheSpotMessaging: Bool = true
    @State var textTyped: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        if (showOnTheSpotMessaging) {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                        ScrollView {
                            LazyVStack {
                                ForEach(viewModel.messagesDBArray, id: \.id) { message in
                                    MessageBubble(message: message)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.top, 10)
                        .background(.gray)
                        .onChange(of: viewModel.messagesDBArray.count) { id in
                            
                            withAnimation {
                                proxy.scrollTo(id, anchor: .bottom)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame( height: 200, alignment: .bottomLeading)
                }
                HStack () {
                    TextEditor (text: $textTyped)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .leading)
                    Button ("Send", action: {
                        viewModel.messagesDBArray.append(SingleMessageBubbleModel(text: textTyped, received: true, timeStamp: Date()))
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that this is clear to you and that it has been useful

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any idea why the `proxy.scrollTo(id, anchor: .bottom)` doesn't trigger although the `observed object` array gets updated? I mean it doesn't scroll to the bottom when new message is sent.